# Why Grothendieck group of an Abelian category is well-defined?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

According to nlab, the Grothendieck group $K(\mathfrak{A})$ of a small Abelian category $\mathfrak{A}$ is the set of isomorphism classes of objects in $\mathfrak{A}$, and $[A]+[B] = [C]$ iff there is a short exact sequence $0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$.

Clearly $[A]+[B] = [A\oplus B]$ since $0\to A\to A\oplus B\to B\to 0$ is short exact.

To show that addition is well-defined, we have to show that for every short exact sequence $0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$, there exists an arrow $A\oplus B\to C$ making the obvious diagram commute, (Five Lemma implies that any such arrow is an isomorphism), but I can't figure out why such an arrow exists?

An abstract proof (one without assuming $\mathfrak{A}$ as sets) would be greatly appreciated, but I acknowledge we can argue with R-modules and use the embedding theorem.

Comment: I don't really know anything about the subject, but my understanding of that page is that to get the Grothendieck group you start with the free group on the symbols $[A]$ of isomorphism classes, and then mod out by any relation of the the kind you wrote. You seem to want that $C$ is isomorphic to $A\oplus B$ whenever it fits in a short exact sequence, but that definitely isn't true ($0\rightarrow \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\rightarrow 0$).

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the addition in $K(\mathfrak{A})$ is not well defined? Since $[A]+[B]$ produces two different isomorphism classes.

Comment: It's well-defined. You start with a group (this big free abelian group) and then mod out by some relations (the subgroup generated by $[A] + [B] - [C]$ when there is such an exact sequence) and use the induced addition on the quotient. As you observe, $[A] + [B]$ can have two different (nonisomorphic) representatives but they're still equal modulo these relations.

Comment: @TokenToucan Thanks that makes all the sense!

Answer (score 1):

The statement you are asking for is not true, but also not necessary. Note that there is an error in your first line: the Grothendieck group is not the set of isomorphism classes in $\mathfrak{A}$, but is only generated by these, modulo the relations from short exact sequences. Thus whenever

$$0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$$

is a short exact sequence in $\mathfrak{A}$, it is indeed the case that $[C]=[A\oplus B]$ in $K(\mathfrak{A})$. This does not imply or require that $C\cong A\oplus B$, it just means that $[C]$ turns out to be a redundant generator, because it is equal to the generator $[A\oplus B]$. This behaviour is even generic: most abelian categories of interest (e.g. modules over a non-semi-simple ring) have short exact sequences in which the middle term is not isomorphic to the direct sum of the outer ones. If a Jordan–Hölder theorem holds in $\mathfrak{A}$, then $[X]\in K(\mathfrak{A})$ remembers only the multiplicities of the simple composition factors of $X$, not the isomorphism class.